# Low level pointers in haskell

Tags: pointers, haskell, ffi

The foreign function interface allows haskell to work with C world. Now Haskell side allows working with the pointers using `Storable` instances. So for example If I have an array of integers in the C world, a plausible representation of that in the haskell world would be `Ptr Int`. Now suppose I want to translate the C expression `a[0] = a[0] + 1`. The only way to do that on the haskell side is to peek int out and then poke back the result of the addition. The problem with this approach is a temporary value is created as a result of that. (I am not sure an optimizing compiler can always avoid doing that)

Now most people might think this effect to be harmless, but think of a situation where the Pointer object contains some sensitive data. I have created this pointer on the c side in such a way that it always guaranteed that its content will never be swapped out of the memory (using mlock system call). Now peeking the result on the haskell side no more guarantees the security of the sensitive data.

So what should be the best way to avoid that in the haskell world? Has anybody else ran into similar problems with low level pointer manipulations in haskell.

Comment: Can you clarify how swapping out is harmful? If you mean that someone can later scan the disk to find the swapped out value, then the same can be said about other C side stuff. Once you start using that "sensitive value", you cannot predict where it will end up - even the stack, the local variables, registers in the task state, ....can all move to the disk. I would expect that memory regions are locked for performance reasons - for example, don't swap out Java Heap, because swapping out rarely accessed heap pages can make GC slow.

Comment: You can lock a memory using mlock system call. So for example if you lock the above array, it is guaranteed to be never swapped out. libgcrypt which is used by programs like gnupg use it to lock sensitive information in the memory for security reasons.

Comment: Since I can not lock pure haskell values as they can be moved around by the garbage collector, I have to work with secure memory allocated on the c side (using ForeignPtr in my case).

Comment: The mlock calls are usually don on void* or char*. I'v never seen it done on int*, for 'security' reasons.

Comment: @jonke How is mlock on char* secure compared to mlock on int*?

Comment: @Satvik, https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEM06-C.+Ensure+that+sensitive+data+is+not+written+out+to+disk. I don't mean mlock is totally secure on char * buffer, but examples using int* and mlock usually is for the other usage of mlock (realtime system)and the only usages of mlock in a secure context  (that I have seen) is by mlock a char* and only operate on data within that buffer.

Answer (score 3):

I just built a test case with the code:

```
foo :: Ptr CInt -> IO ()
foo p = peek p >>= poke p ∘ (+1)
```

And using GHC 7.6.3 `-fllvm -O2 -ddump-asm` I see the relevant instructions:

```
0x0000000000000061 <+33>:    mov    0x7(%r14),%rax
0x0000000000000065 <+37>:    incl   (%rax)
```

So it loads an address into `rax` and increments the memory at that address.  Seems to be what you'd get in other languages, but let's see.

With C, I think the fair comparison is:

```
void foo(int *p)
{
    p[0]++;
}
```

Which results in:

```
0x0000000000000000 <+0>:     addl   $0x1,(%rdi)
```

All this said, I freely admit that it is not clear to me what you are concerned about so I might have missed your point and in doing so addressed the wrong thing.

Comment: Suppose I do `a <- peek p`. Now is `a` allocated a separate memory which is handled by the garbage collector? In your case I suppose the compiler has optimized to share the same memory but will that always be the case.

Comment: There is nothing guaranteeing this will always be the case.  If you must control what is in registers and what is not, or what is allocated and potentially stored in a heap and what is not, then I don't have a convincing solution for you besides generating or writing in some language and using a matching compiler that gives you these guarantees then making foreign bindings to access the functionality in Haskell.  Is this a crypto-key you are working so hard to protect?

Comment: Also, it is probably worth noting C doesn't give such a promise.  You can probably accept that it will result in a memory increment instruction, but there is no promise it won't get moved to a register first (and perhaps context switched, stored in memory, and swapped to the hard drive).  If this concerns you too, then assembly or dedicated hardware seems to be your main options.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts regarding non safety on the C side.

Comment: I think working with the assembly directly is the only way I can guarantee it will never be swapped out? I hope I can provide some abstractions using that to guarantee the same on the haskell side too.